# Balancing forces in simple pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Let us assume an object of mass $m$ is performing SHM in pendulum. At an instant, let the object make $\theta$ angle with the vertical line. Now, in books it is given that tension $T$ of the string is given as $T=mg\cos \theta$ and $mg\sin \theta$ is the restoring force. My question is why should $T$ be $mg\cos \theta$. If the object would perform circular motion it would make sense to me that $T=mg\cos \theta ± \frac{mv^2}{r}$. However, the pendulum performs linear motion in this case,so what is the logic behind $T=mg\cos \theta$? What will happen if it didn't equal to $mg\cos \theta$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to understand the ambiguity of vector resolvation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/656882/how-to-understand-the-ambiguity-of-vector-resolvation)

Comment: Hmm in the first post,it was said that vertically there is an accelaration $a_y$ which I didn't understand.At maximum height there isn't any vertical acceleration which i can notice.The only acceleration i noticed is along the arc bob traversed which is $g\sin \theta$. Could you please point out that vertical acceleration?

Comment: Simple answer: arc and the vertical axis are **not** perpendicular at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it should be $T = mg\cos\theta + \frac{mv^2}L$ where $L$ is the length of the string. It is only $T = mg\cos\theta $ at the point of highest altitude since there $v=0$.

It is easy to see if we write the equations of motion in the polar coordinate system centered at the pivot point:

\begin{align}
\hat{r}:& \qquad -T+mg\cos\theta = m(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2)\\
\hat{\theta}:& \qquad -mg\sin\theta = m(r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}).
\end{align}
Since $r \equiv L$ is constant, we have $\dot{r}=\ddot{r}=0$ and hence
$$T= mg\cos\theta + mL\dot{\theta}^2$$
while the second equation implies the equation of motion
$$\ddot{\theta} = -\frac{g}{L}\sin\theta.$$